# Seam 2.0.3.CR1 xcss file not getting picked up

Tags: css, richfaces, seam

I have an example Seam project that I am working with. I am trying to add a xcss file which I have added to the project under the resources folder org/jboss/seam/ui/richfaces/styles.xcss , I have included the following line in the template.xhtml file :

`<a:loadStyle src="resource:///org/jboss/seam/ui/richfaces/styles.xcss"/>`

but am confronted with the following exception :

org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Static resource not found for path /org/jboss/seam/ui/richfaces/styles.xcss

what am I missing?

Comment: I had not included in my build file!

Comment: <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
          <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources"> 
             <include name="**/*.xcss"/>
          </fileset>
     </copy>